# i need to sort a python list of lists by date

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I need to sort a list of lists by date:

```
mylist=['ML-M01 Qual Report 07/31/13', 'ML36220010 Complete Qual Testing 07/24/13', 'ML36220045 Final FRB 07/13/13', 'ML9822D2600 Brief to PM 08/5/13']
```

from this site, I got this code:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%m/%d/%y'))
```

however, I get this error message:

```
sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%m/%d/%y'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%m/%d/%y'))
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <lambda>
  sorted(mylist,key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x[2], '%m/%d/%y'))
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\_strptime.py", line 330, in strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=-  fmt=%m/%d/%y
```

need help - need to sort the list by the 3d element - oldest to newest

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each entry in your list is a string, not a list, so `x[2]` is a single character (`'-'` for your first entry). You need to split out *just* the date portion to `strptime()`:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.rsplit(None, 1)[-1], '%m/%d/%y'))
```

The `str.rsplit()` splits on whitespace, *once*, for efficiency:

```
>>> 'ML-M01 Qual Report 07/31/13'.rsplit(None, 1)
['ML-M01 Qual Report', '07/31/13']
>>> 'ML-M01 Qual Report 07/31/13'.rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
'07/31/13'
```

Result:

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.rsplit(None, 1)[-1], '%m/%d/%y'))
['ML36220045 Final FRB 07/13/13', 'ML36220010 Complete Qual Testing 07/24/13', 'ML-M01 Qual Report 07/31/13', 'ML9822D2600 Brief to PM 08/5/13']
```

Note that `sorted()` returns a new sorted list, the original list is not affected. If you want to sort `mylist` in place, call the `list.sort()` method on it:

```
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.rsplit(None, 1)[-1], '%m/%d/%y'))
```

Comment: For your sample input, I get sorted output. Did you want to sort `mylist` in place?

Comment: got it.  i don't really understand the code, but it works great!  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your error:

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=-  fmt=%m/%d/%y
```

Indicates that you got data `"-"` which is not a date. This indicates that you have lines in your list that won't contain a valid date.

This solution deals with invalid dates by returning `None`. That will put all invalid dates together:

```
import datetime

mylist=['ML-M01 Qual Report 07/31/13', 'ML36220010 Complete Qual Testing 07/24/13', 'ML36220045 Final FRB 07/13/13', 'ML9822D2600 Brief to PM 08/5/13']

def extract_date(text):
    try:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(text.rsplit(None, 1)[-1], '%m/%d/%y')
    except ValueError:
        return None

mylist.sort(key=extract_date)

print mylist
```

Output:

```
['ML36220045 Final FRB 07/13/13', 
 'ML36220010 Complete Qual Testing 07/24/13', 
 'ML-M01 Qual Report 07/31/13', 
 'ML9822D2600 Brief to PM 08/5/13']
```