# How do I show the "X" axis scale in hours, minutes and seconds?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Data were converted using Python dictionary according to [Create a new table in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826768/create-a-new-table-in-python/56827170#56827170) user titusarmah99 https://stackoverflow.com/users/8363478/titusarmah99

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("ggplot")


%matplotlib inline 


%config InlineBackend.figure_format='svg'}
```

**Reading the Sandvik.log and Iscar.log files.**

```
            data=[]
        with open('Sandvik.log','r') as file:
            for row in file:
                data.append(row.rstrip('\n').split('|'))
        columns =['DateTime','Xload']

        data_dic = []
        for row in data:
            tmp ={}
            tmp['DateTime']=row[0]
            for i in range(1,len(row)-1):
                if row[i] in columns:
                    tmp[row[i]]=row[i+1]
            for c in columns:
                if c not in tmp:
                    tmp[c] = '' #for rows which donot have the property
            data_dic.append(tmp)

            dfs = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
        print (dfs.dtypes)



    # Reading Iscar.log    

    data=[]
    with open('Iscar.log','r') as file:
        for row in file:
            data.append(row.rstrip('\n').split('|'))
    columns =['DateTime','Xload']

    data_dic = []
    for row in data:
        tmp ={}
        tmp['DateTime']=row[0]
        for i in range(1,len(row)-1):
            if row[i] in columns:
                tmp[row[i]]=row[i+1]
        for c in columns:
            if c not in tmp:
                tmp[c] = '' #for rows which donot have the property
        data_dic.append(tmp)

        dfi = pd.DataFrame(data_dic)
    print (dfi.dtypes) 


    # Converting the Xload and Datetime variables
    dfs['Xload']=pd.to_numeric(dfs.Xload)

    dfs['DateTime']= pd.to_datetime(dfs['DateTime']) 

    dfi['Xload']=pd.to_numeric(dfi.Xload)

    dfi['DateTime']= pd.to_datetime(dfi['DateTime']) 


# removing null data
dfs.dropna(inplace=True)
dfi.dropna(inplace=True)


# Reset the DataFrame
dfs.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
dfi.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

**Graphing the Xload variable for the Sandvik DataFrame.**

```
dfs.plot('DateTime', color = "red", figsize = (8, 6))

plt.ylim(0,100) # scale up to 100% for Y axis

# creating subtitles
plt.legend(['Sandvik'], loc='upper left') 
plt.title("Machining Time vs. Xload Power")
plt.xlabel("Machining Time")
plt.ylabel("% in Xload variable")
```

[**Dataframe Sandvik Chart**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJuIv.jpg)

**Graphing the Xload variable for the Iscar DataFrame**

```
dfi.plot('DateTime', color = "royalblue", figsize = (8, 6))

plt.ylim(0,100)

# creating subtitles
plt.legend(['Iscar'], loc='upper left') 
plt.title("Machining Time vs Xload Power")
plt.xlabel("Machining Time")
plt.ylabel("% in Xload variable")
```

[**Dataframe Iscar Chart**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mFoD.jpg)

**I cannot scale the hour, minute and second to the "X" axis after joining both graphs.**

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))

for frame in [dfs, dfi]:
    plt.plot(frame['Xload'])


#plt.xlim()
plt.ylim(0,100)

# Criando as legendas
plt.legend(['Sandvik', 'Iscar'], shadow=True, loc='upper left') 
plt.title("Machining Time vs Xload Power")
plt.xlabel("Machining Time")
plt.ylabel("% in Xload variable")
```

[**Grouped Charts**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBMLE.jpg)

I will only use the scale in seconds dt.strftime ('% S').
I need to **overlay** the graphs (Sandvik and Iscar) and change the ordered X-axis scale **every 5 seconds**.

```
dfs['DateTime'] = dfs['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%S') 
dfi['DateTime'] = dfi['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%S')

# overlapping graphics
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 4))
for frame in [dfs, dfi]:
    plt.plot(frame['Xload'])
    plt.legend(['Sandvik', 'Iscar'], loc='upper left') #plot da legend

#plt.xlim()
plt.ylim(0,100)


# using seaborn
x1 = dfs['DateTime']
x2 = dfi['DateTime']
y1 = dfs['Xload']
y2 = dfi['Xload']

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, sharey=True, figsize=(10,4))
ax = sns.lineplot(x=x1, y=y1, ax=ax1, color='blue', label='Sardvik', ci=None)
ax = sns.lineplot(x=x2, y=y2, ax=ax2, color='red', label='Iscar', ci=None)

ax1.set_xlim(min(x1), max(x1))
ax2.set_xlim(min(x2), max(x2))
ax1.set_xlabel('Machine Time')
ax2.set_xlabel('Machine Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('% in Xload variable')
ax1.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks()[::5])
ax2.set_xticks(ax2.get_xticks()[::5])
plt.setp( ax1.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90 )
plt.setp( ax2.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit the question for adding more information. Try not to post it as answers.

As you may have noticed, the timestamps in `Sardvik.log` and `Iscar.log` used for plotting are around 10 minutes apart from each other.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (20, 6))
for frame in [dfs, dfi]:
    plt.plot(frame['DateTime'],frame['Xload'])

#plt.xlim()
plt.ylim(0,100)

# Criando as legendas
plt.legend(['Sandvik', 'Iscar'], shadow=True, loc='upper left') 
plt.title("Machining Time vs Xload Power")
plt.xlabel("Machining Time")
plt.ylabel("% in Xload variable")
```

Above code yeilds [image: this plot] which preserves the timestamps but doesn't look good.
If this solves the problem then its great, but just for sake of better visualization, you can plot them as subplot ([see example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)) or [broken axes using seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006289/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-broken-axis-graph-with-seaborn).

```
# adding these two lines before removing null
dfs['DateTime'] = dfs['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f') 
dfi['DateTime'] = dfi['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')

# using seaborn
x1 = dfs['DateTime']
x2 = dfi['DateTime']
y1 = dfs['Xload']
y2 = dfi['Xload']

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=1, sharey=True, figsize=(10,6))
ax = sns.lineplot(x=x1, y=y1, ax=ax1, color='blue', label='Sardvik', ci=None)
ax = sns.lineplot(x=x2, y=y2, ax=ax2, color='red', label='Iscar', ci=None)

ax1.set_xlim(min(x1), max(x1))
ax2.set_xlim(min(x2), max(x2))
ax1.set_xlabel('Machine Time')
ax2.set_xlabel('Machine Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('% in Xload variable')
ax1.set_xticks(ax1.get_xticks()[::10])
ax2.set_xticks(ax2.get_xticks()[::10])
plt.setp( ax1.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70 )
plt.setp( ax2.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70 )

f.suptitle('Machining Time vs Xload Power')
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=.01, hspace=0)
```

Above code gives [image: this]

Comment: This presentation with **subplots** is very good, but I still need to **overlay** the graphics (Sandvik and Iscar) and change the X-axis scale **every 5 seconds**.

Comment: your Sandvik and Iscar doesnot have same xaxis value, but we can overlay as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32907735/8363478) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733693/matplotlib-overlay-plots-with-different-scales)